# Date format when exported to CSV using Powershell

Tags: datetime, powershell, csv

I Have a powershell script that executes a sql query, then exports the information to a CSV file. However the CSV file reformats all DateTimes entry to `mm/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss`. I need the entries to be in the format `yyyy-mm-dd-hh.mm.ss.00`

```shell
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $sqlSelectCVS
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$SqlAdapter.Fill($export)

#Close the SQL connection
$SqlConnection.Close()

#Creates the New file with out Column header inforamtion
$export.tables[0] |export-csv -Path ($ExportTo + '\' + $ExportName) -notypeinformation 
(Get-Content ($ExportTo + '\' + $ExportName)| Select-Object -Skip 1) | Set-Content      ($ExportTo + '\' + $ExportName)
```

The database connections and query work just fine. Also as a side note Ive tried opening it in notepad with no luck and the date is a future date.. 
I am still very new to powershell so if you could explain any suggestions so i could understand it, i would appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use .NET libraries in PowerShell to format the string, like so:

```
"{0:yyyy-mm-dd-hh.hh.mm.ss.00}" -f [datetime]$stringOrWhateverDateVariable
```

$stringOrWhateverDateVariable would be the date variable from the SQL table.

I cannot test on an SQL datababe, but it works for strings to your DateTime format.

Comment: Yours works for write-output. but when i transfer it over to a CSV file it changes to "length" "25"

Comment: @user2788724 Can you update the question , append an edit at the end with your current export with the method I listed?